# Python 3 Read File To Array Separated By Every Second :

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, file

I have a file with text formatted as such

```
0 :text here:
1 :some text here:
2 :more text here:
```

I need to be able to grab the text within the two colons and put them into the next element of an array while ignoring the preceding line numbers AKA the 0, 1, and 2. These line numbers are meant to indicate what array position the proceeding text will be placed in.

so my result array should look like this.

```
array[0] == "text here"
array[1] == "some text here"
array[2] == "more text here"
```

I would prefer solutions that are syntactically easy to follow.

Comment: What do you mean with while ignore the preceding line numbers?

Comment: `[val for idx, val in enumerate(s.split(":")) if idx % 2 == 1]`

Comment: You can use the `split()` method as suggested by @dekauliya or you could also use regular expressions such as `import re; re.findall(":(.+):", my_string)`. If you decide to use regular expressions, you may need to modify the pattern somewhat depending on what sort of characters separate the lines of your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work well and made the most sense to me

```
import csv

array = []

with open('text.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=':') # splits data at :
    for row in csv_reader: # Iterate through each row of file
        array.append(row[1]) # Grab second element in the row
    print("array: ", array)
```

Output Should Be

Array: ['text here', 'some text here', 'more text here']